# Physics solver parameters and BDI behavior controller

Tags: gazebo-1.5

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I just installed the latest DRCSim (had to compile from source because although Gazebo 1.5 was added to the repository, DRCSim 2.2 wasn't). As we work mainly on getting the robot to walk, the first thing we tried is the BDI behavior controller which produces a fine walking gait.
It was clear from the tutorial that this runs with different solver parameters so we got curious about what happens with normal parameters and found out that a small change in any of the parameters will cause the controller to fail (the robot joints don't behave as expected causing the robot to fall).
The question is: what will the solver parameters be during the qualifications and the VRC?
Which approach would you recommend for developing a walking algorithm if the behavior changes so drastically depending on the solver parameters?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1747/physics-solver-parameters-and-bdi-behavior-controller/) by [EricSidorov](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/116/ericsidorov/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 53 on 2013-03-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Please direct question related to VRC rules to http://theroboticschallenge.com/.

I can't offer any recommendations on developing a walking controller because I have never implemented one.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0